# Need some advise on PHP Session multidimensional array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, session, multidimensional-array

Good morning,

I'm just stuck within an issue which I can't follow even in the logical way. Maybe you can help me out by leading me to the right path.

I have a simple button which starts a simple function handing over an id. Right now I do have multiple buttons in a row with different ids

`<a class="buttonControl btn btn-default btn-xs" href="javascript:play(999)" id="999">Play</a>
<br>
<a class="buttonControl btn btn-default btn-xs" href="javascript:play(888)" id="888">Play</a>`

Next thing is I have a multidimensional array in php out of a php session.

```
$arr_a = array(
    "999" => array(
        "start" => "180",       
        "files" => array(
            "mp3" => "http://example.com/999.mp3"           
         )
    )
    "888" => array(
        "start" => "120",       
        "files" => array(
            "mp3" => "http://example.com/888.mp3"           
         )
    )
)
```

The JS function play(id) starts playing the audio file via the html5 audio object.

```
function play(x) {
  ...some code... get audio object ...
}
```

So am I right, when I describe the following:

- convert the php array with json_encode [ ? ]
- make JSON output available in js function [ ? ]
- iterate through the json data until id match with key [ ? ]
- get the 'mp3' value and hand it over to src audio object [ ? ]
- play the file

So is this the right way from your point of view?

Thank you so much!

Best Regards
Aaren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use json to change the context from php to javascript. The other steps are all right. But where do you struggle?

```
function play(x) {
  let jsonData = <?=json_encode($arr_a);?>;
  let mp3 = jsonData[x].files.mp3;
  document.querySelector('audio').src = mp3;
  document.querySelector('audio').play();
}
```

Comment: Right now I think it was really good to re-think and to write everything down, so I think my struggle was only because I was somehow unsure (lack of coffee maybe) ... however writing it down and think about it while writing it down AND your re-check about my thoughts helped me so far! Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome. If you have any further questions, please feel free to ask. If this is the answer to your question, please select it as your prefered answer :)

Comment: Would be yours but I have to wait for 8 minutes due to some time restrictions. Thank you! Now I can enjoy my coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

If your list can change, you can use a PHP script (audio_list.php, for example) to return the list as a JSON, and use an ajax call to get the updated list.

Comment: Thank you. Right now the list comes from the php session therefore I can easily convert it to json. So Joshuas attempt helped me further.